# Ansible get unique value in loop for register

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Hi friend below is my sample output from a regsiter name dataInfo

```
ok: [123.23.44.123] => {
    "msg": [ 
        {
            "changed": true,  
            "item": [
                {
                    "artifactName": "helloWorld.jar", 
                    "status": "false" 
                }, 
                "myGroup1"
            ], 
            "rc": 0,
            "stderr_lines": [], 
            "stdout": "ok", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "ok"
            ]
        },
        {
            "changed": true,  
            "item": [
                {
                    "artifactName": "helloWorld.jar", 
                    "status": "false" 
                }, 
                "myGroup2"
            ], 
            "rc": 0,
            "stderr_lines": [], 
            "stdout": "ok", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "ok"
            ]
        }
```

Below is my code

```
- name: My ArtifactName Name
  debug:
    msg: "artifactName = {{ item.item[0].artifactName }}"
  loop: "{{ dataInfo.results }}"
  when: item.changed | bool == true and item.stdout == "ok"
```

How can i only display as below

```
artifactName = helloWorld.jar
```

rather than

```
artifactName = helloWorld.jar
artifactName = helloWorld.jar
```

I have shared my code as shown above. Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looping with `dataInfo.results`, the `debug` message will repeat for each "item". If you only want unique `artifactName`, then you can save it to a variable using `json_query` and choose to display only `unique` ones.

Something like this:

```yaml
    # Save list of artifactName found in dataInfo.results even with duplicates
    - name: save artifact names
      set_fact:
        artifact_names: "{{ artifact_names | default([]) + [ item | json_query('item[].artifactName') ] }}"
      loop: "{{ dataInfo.results }}"
    # Show each item of artifact_names using unique filter to eliminate duplicates
    - name: show unique artifact names
      debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ artifact_names | flatten | unique }}"
```

---

**Update:**

Below `set_fact`:

```yaml
artifact_names: "{{ artifact_names | default([]) + [ item.item[0].artifactName ] }}"
```

... will work if you get only 1 hash in `item` like this:

```json
            "item": [
                {
                    "artifactName": "helloWorld.jar", 
                    "status": "false" 
                }, 
            ],
```

But if it may have multiple hashes like below, it won't work:

```json
            "item": [
                {
                    "artifactName": "helloWorld.jar", 
                    "status": "false" 
                }, 
                {
                    "artifactName": "someother.jar", 
                    "status": "false" 
                },
                ...
            ],
```

If this is a possibility, then `json_query` should be used. It can be used exactly like the `jq` command.

Comment: can i know 'show unique artifact names' can it be done in form of loop as based on the name i need execute a command.. it should not be like a string. it should loop one item per jar name

Comment: You can loop with `artifact_names` and access each `item`. I will update the answer.

Comment: I tried it, but u:helloWorld.jar
 is being printed instead of helloWorld.jar

Comment: It's an array item. So it's printing with unicode, use the `flatten` filter to `loop` as updated in the answer.

Comment: hi i search online and Ansible documentation but i still dont understand its purpose of flatten. Is there otehr ways instead using json_query, we use directly item.item[0].artifactName

Comment: [flatten filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)  "flattens" multiple lists into one. If you try debug without `flatten` you will see something like: `[u'helloWorld.jar']`  which is array item 0.

Comment: `item.item[0].artifactName`  can be used if you are guaranteed to always get only one `artifactName` in `item[]`.

Comment: hi, can use as below right
artifact_names: "{{ artifact_names | default([]) + [ item.item[0].artifactName ] }}"
i tested was working. i like you to review as well

Comment: i'm trying to understand json_query but not sure how the logic works. i am performing research on json_query

Comment: I updated the answer (again) with clarification on `item.item[0].artifactName`.

Comment: nice. it really helpful to me and those in future